# Meteor with web services instead of mongo?

Tags: meteor

I have to rewrite a front end of an app. can I use meteor as a front end and in the server side instead of call to Mongo I call web services on secure farm? 
is Meteor good fit for this design pattern? each user only gets information related to his own so the call to web services are managable.

My web services are in XML right now, I will be able to change them to JSON but is Meteor able to handle XML and convert them to JSON on it's own or with a help of a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make that work somehow (and converting xml to json is not hard and yes there are most definitely packages for that). However, it was recently announced that there will be native support for this in the near future:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d0xTR-eYh0#